# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bussiness'

Tags: python, django

This is the `/app03/views.py`:

```
from django.db import models

def business(request):
    v = models.Bussiness.objects.all()   # this is the line10
    # QuerySet
    # [obj(id, caption, code), obj,obj...]
    return render(request, '/app03/business.html', {'v':v})
```

This is the traceback information in my PyCharm CE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/TestPython/pyProject/app03/views.py", line 10, in business
    v = models.Bussiness.objects.all()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bussiness'
[14/Aug/2017 09:27:27] "GET /app03/business/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64817
```

In my `/app03/models.py`:

```
class Bussiness(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='SA')
```

and, I have done this operation:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and in the db.sqlite3, have generated the `app03_bussiness` table:

[image]

Why there is no attribute 'Bussiness'?

Comment: How are you importing the `models` module?

Comment: @Kendas in views.py I did.

Comment: You're importing the `django.db.models` module not the `app03.models` module. The first doesn't contain your `Business` model. The answer below should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the class from your app model directly. You're currently in conflict with Django's `models` module, which has has the same name `models` with that in your app:

```
from django.db import models
from app03.models import Bussiness

def business(request):
    v = Bussiness.objects.all()   # this is the line10
    # QuerySet
    # [obj(id, caption, code), obj,obj...]
    return render(request, '/app03/business.html', {'v':v})
```

Comment: But, however, i have a similar directory named app02, it use the models like app03, do not have this error, I don't know where gets this conflict.

Comment: You probably don't need to import `django.db.models` into your views which contains the class your custom models inherit. You should import each model class from each app.